# Different behavior of variable and return value of function

Tags: variables, go, return-value, slice

I want to join two lines, but I get an error message.

Original:

```
hash := sha1.Sum([]byte(uf.Pwd))
u.Pwhash = hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])
```

Joint:

```
u.Pwhash = hex.EncodeToString(sha1.Sum([]byte(uf.Pwd))[:])
```

The first one works fine, the second produces the error message:

```
models/models.go:104: invalid operation sha1.Sum(([]byte)(uf.Pwd))[:] (slice of unaddressable value)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get an error message in the 2nd case because you try to slice the return value of a function call (that of `sha1.Sum()`):

```
sha1.Sum(([]byte)(uf.Pwd))[:]
```

The return values of function calls are not addressable. As a reminder, (only) the following are addressable (taken from [Spec: Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)):

> ...a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, `x` may also be a (possibly parenthesized) [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

And slicing an array requires the array to be addressable. [Spec: Slice expressions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

> If the sliced operand is an array, it must be [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) and the result of the slice operation is a slice with the same element type as the array.

Your first case works because you first store the returned array in a local variable which is addressable.

Slicing an array requires the array to be addressable because slicing results in a slice which will not copy the data of the array but create a slice which shares the backing array and will only point/refer to it.